# How to convert tuples into dict Value

Tags: python

This is my tuples
'''

```
tuples_variable = [(1, 'Singed', 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Singed.png', 0, '55.76%', '3.58%', '3.53%'), (2, 'Ahri', 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Ahri.png', 1, '50.71%', '16.58%', '18.71%')]
```

'''
How I can change it into dictionary with this same format?
'''

```
dict = [{
Rank: '1',
ChampionName: 'Singed',
ChampionImage: 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Singed.png',
Tier: '0',
Win Rate: '55.76%',
Pick Rate: '3.58%',
Ban Rate: '3.53%',
},
{
#second index of tuples 
Rank: '2',
ChampionName: 'Ahri',
ChampionImage: 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Ahri.png',
Tier: '1',
Win Rate: '50.71%',
Pick Rate: '16.58%',
Ban Rate: '18.71%',
}

]
```

'''
I have this kind of tuples How I can change it, into this?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a tuple of the keys you want for your dictionaries:

```
keys = ("Rank","ChampionName","ChampionImage","Tier","Win","Pick","Ban")
```

Then you can `zip()` that with each tuple in a list comprehension to make a list of dicts:

```
keys = ("Rank","ChampionName","ChampionImage","Tier","Win","Pick","Ban")
tuples_variable = [(1, 'Singed', 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Singed.png', 0, '55.76%', '3.58%', '3.53%'), (2, 'Ahri', 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Ahri.png', 1, '50.71%', '16.58%', '18.71%')]

l = [dict(zip(keys, t)) for t in tuples_variable]
```

This will produced `l` of:

```
[{'Rank': 1,
  'ChampionName': 'Singed',
  'ChampionImage': 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Singed.png',
  'Tier': 0,
  'Win': '55.76%',
  'Pick': '3.58%',
  'Ban': '3.53%'},
 {'Rank': 2,
  'ChampionName': 'Ahri',
  'ChampionImage': 'https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/lol/champion/Ahri.png',
  'Tier': 1,
  'Win': '50.71%',
  'Pick': '16.58%',
  'Ban': '18.71%'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension?

```
[{'Rank': a, 'ChampionName': b, 'ChampionImage': c, 'Tier': d, 'Win Rate': e, 'Pick Rate': f, 'Ban Rate': g} for a, b, c, d, e, f, g in tuples_variable]
```

And don't name your variables the name of built-in types like `dict`.